# Grouping people with the same address

Tags: mysql

Following is my sql query in which i am trying to get the names of those people whose address is same but the problem i faced is that the query is showing the right count but all the names are not there grouped by and not in the following manner. Kindly let me know how can i modify the following query so i can get the address in a manner mentioned below and also count(address) = 1 should be ignored. Thanks,

```
+---------------------+
 Jhon  | Stree 9, H#4
 zame  | Stree 9, H#4
 sinn  | Stree 9, H#4
 linn  | Stree 8, H#9
 tinn  | Stree 8, H#9
+---------------------+
```

```
SELECT *,count(address) FROM `student` 
group by address
order by  count(address) desc
```

**SQLFIDDLE:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d6ca/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT name, count(address) FROM student 
 GROUP BY address 
 ORDER BY count(address), name DESC
```

EDIT:
do you mean this group_concat ?

```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name DESC SEPARATOR ' ')as name, 
    adress FROM student 
   GROUP BY adress 
  ORDER BY count(adress), name DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dcf4/10)

Comment: Well  i meant not aligning names in alphabetical order but displaying record of those in a group whose adress is same

Comment: kindly see the example i mentioned in my question, which is showing those records first whose address is same and highest count of address people have in common and so on but those addresses should be discarded as well whose `count(address) = 1`

Comment: how to populate the names in the next row currently all the names are grouped in one row

Comment: Thanks, issue is being solved. I would appreciate if you also let me know how to mention each name in new row for same address

Comment: by this `explode(' ',$row['name']) `